# Call server-side method in the onclick method in jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have one method in backend coding using c#. Now, I want to call it on onClick event of button using jQuery which is in design part.

Please help me to solve the problem.
Check out below code for example.

**.aspx Page**

```
$("#SubmitButton").click(function() {
 // Call method BindData();
});
```

**.aspx.cs Page**

```
public void BindData()
{
      // Code to bind datalist
}
```

Comment: You want to call it how? Is this web forms or MVC?

Comment: it is web form. i have button click event using jQuery in .aspx page. And method is in .aspx.cs page. I want to call that method on button click event of jquery.

Comment: And is this just a method you've written, or is it the `Click` event of the `Button` you want to execute?

Comment: yeah, i want to execute method on Click event of the Button. I am binding datalist.

Comment: can you porvide sample code?

Comment: what inside BindData?

Comment: I am binding datalist inside BindData.

Comment: maybe in your case it is easier to use asp.button with server-side OnClick?

Comment: Fixed my original answer

Comment: @Grundy, yes, I can easily execute asp.button with server-side OnClick. But my page is developed such a way that, I can't use OnClick event.

Comment: @JeetenParmar do you checked my sample?

Answer (score 1):

ASPX

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction() {
        // some stuff
        return true; // important
    }
</script>

<asp:Button runat="server" ID="SubmitButton"
    OnClientClick="return myFunction();"
    OnClick="SubmitButton_Click" />
```

Code-behind

```
protected void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BindData();
}
```

By specifying OnClientClick you're telling your button that it should first execute the Javascript method. If the method returns `false`, there is no postback. However, if it returns `true`, the button's handler in code-behind will also be called.

Comment: The OP stated that he's got some C# code server-side that he wants to execute.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud I thought of it the other way around :). This should hopefully be OK.

Answer (score 1):

if i understand right you want something like this

```
    $("#SubmitButton").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "index.aspx/BindData",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify({ }),
            dataType: "json",      
        });
    });
```

and make your method static and add attribute [WebMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.webmethodattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like:

```
[WebMethod]
public static void BindData()
{
  // Code
}
```

but you will not be able to change the state of server controls

Comment: @JeetenParmar can you specify exactly what you want to do? maybe provide more code and html

Comment: @Grundy What If I want to generate a PDF from webMethod? With Response.Write()?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale, you can ask own question, and provide needed information, now i now quite understand what you already have and what you want get.

Answer (score 0):

in your css :

```
.hide
{
  display:none;
}
```

then

```
<asp:Button runat="server" id="btn" onclick="btn_OnClick"  CssClass="hide"/>
<div onclick="TestCall();return true;">Click Me !!</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
function TestCall()
{
    var btn = $('#<%= btn.ClientID %>');
    btn.click();
}

</script>
```

hope , helps you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Add a APSBUTTON set onclick method on code behind then set CssClass to Hide means declare a style class contain display:none like this

```
<style>
.hide
{
display:none;
}
</style>
```

Button Sample :

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" CssClass="hide" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

JavaScript Sample :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

//With jQuery 

$('#<%=Button1.ClientID%>').click();

</script>
```

that should be work for this case

good luck