# Jquery Call C# event method

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I want to call C# Event method

```
protected void btnSelectPaymentService_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    object rbtn = Request.Form["serviceID"];

    if (rbtn != null)
    {
        SelectedPaymentServiceID = Convert.ToInt32(rbtn);
        multiviewOnlinePayments.ActiveViewIndex = -1;
        multiviewOnlinePayments.SetActiveView(viewPaymentInfo);

        panelPayControls.Visible = false;

        btnAddPayment.Visible = false;
        btnGetPaymentInfo.Visible = true;
        btnGetPaymentInfoOther.Visible = false;

        //Page.Form.DefaultFocus = btnGetPaymentInfo.UniqueID;
        Page.Form.DefaultButton = btnGetPaymentInfo.UniqueID;
    }
```

But on client side i'm using DIV elements,and on jquery click i want to call this method. what can i do for that?

Comment: you can try something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20118152/1823841

Comment: Using `ajax` or direct `asp`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#divelementId").click(function () {
            $("#buttonId").click();
        });
    });
</script>
```